# Python pandas ISIN with variable

Tags: python, pandas, isin

I could use a hand on using the ISIN pandas function. Basically, I need to aggregate data in a dataframe according to different criteria by year. The issue is that I need to do many aggregations on the data (e.g. country name, funding program, etc.). To make it expedient I am trying to do this in for loops. A simplified example below:

Here I am trying to create a list for each country and pair of programs (ProgA or ProgB).

`aux = EABlock.loc[EABlock["Country"].isin([Ctry]) & EABlock["FundingSource"].isin([Prog]),["2020","2021","2022","2023","2024","2025","2026","2027","2028"]].agg(sum)`

Where Prog = ['ProgA', 'ProgB']

and I get this wrong result (all zeroes):

```
2021    0.0
2022    0.0
2023    0.0
2024    0.0
2025    0.0
2026    0.0
2027    0.0
2028    0.0
```

When instead I write

`aux = EABlock.loc[EABlock["Country"].isin([Ctry]) & EABlock["FundingSource"].isin(["ProgA", "ProgB"]),["2020","2021","2022","2023","2024","2025","2026","2027","2028"]].agg(sum)`

I get the correct result:

```
2020      3.000000
2021    323.216667
2022    127.533333
2023      1.500000
2024   -148.000000
2025    -25.083333
2026    -48.133333
2027   -234.033333
2028      0.000000
```

Further puzzling me is the fact that the criteria seem to be exactly the same:

```
Prog
Out[50]: ['ProgA', 'ProgB']

["ProgA", "ProgB"]
Out[51]: ['ProgA', 'ProgB']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post data sample as text, thanks

Comment: The issue is that `[Prog] ==> [['ProgA', 'ProgB']]` (nested list). It should be `.isin(Prog)` not `.isin([Prog])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not same, if pass list to list then ouput are nested list:

```
EABlock["FundingSource"].isin([Prog])
```

it is same like:

```
EABlock["FundingSource"].isin([["ProgA", "ProgB"]])
```

But you want pass list without `[]`:

```
EABlock["FundingSource"].isin(Prog)
```

It is same like:

```
EABlock["FundingSource"].isin(["ProgA", "ProgB"])
```

Answer (score 1):

See here's the problem,
In the first snippet, you are passing `[Prog]` to isin(), and it is different from passing `["ProgA", "ProgB"]` as in the second snippet.

[image]

The solution is to pass `Prog` without `[]`.

Thank you :)